# FluidPort Connector with start values for composition

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am using OpenModelica for process simulations with multi-component fluids. I noticed that initialization fails on certain instances due to (when composition vector X is set to an array of zeros as an initial estimate in solving initial non-linear set of equations). To avoid it, I had to declare my connectors as follows

```
  package Air = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.MixtureGases.CombustionAir;
  FluidPort  port(redeclare package Medium = Air,
                    Xi_outflow (start=Air.reference_X, fixed=false) ;
```

Nb: My initial conditions are consistent and are sufficient. My issue is the
    non-linear solution initial guesstimates.

Shouldn't the FluidPort connection definition in Modelica automatically include guess values with proper start values?  (I am using latest Modelica 3.2.1 library)